# Firebase user displayName and photoURL don't update when user is created

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a user with firebase, react-native and redux. It all works fine except for the problem that when I create a new user, the first time I go on the profile screen and I log the currentUser the displayName and photoURL are both null. when I refresh the app they are the values that they are supposed to be... I would like for them to be the right value on the first time too.

the redux action

```
export const createUser = (user) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then(userCredentials => {
                if (user.picture) {
                    userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: user.userName,
                        photoURL: user.picture
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS })
                        })
                } else {
                    firebase.storage().ref('images').child('dfp.png').getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                        userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
                            displayName: user.userName,
                            photoURL: url
                        })
                    })
                        .then(() => {
                            dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS })
                        })
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_ERROR, error });
            })
    }
}
```

the redux reducer

```
case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
    console.log('register success')
    return {
       ...state,
       authErrorSingup: null
    }
```

the profile screen

```
const Profile = ({ auth }) => {

    console.log(auth)

    if (auth.photoURL && auth.displayName) {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.background, alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Header screenName="profile" />
                <View style={{ flex: 14 }}>
                    <ScrollView style={{ width: SIZES.width }}>
                        <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
                            <Image
                                source={{ uri: auth.photoURL }}
                                style={styles.profilepictureContainer}
                            />
                            <View style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.secondary, fontSize: SIZES.h3 }}>@{auth.displayName}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", width: SIZES.width / 1.5, marginTop: 10 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.secondary, fontSize: SIZES.h4 }}>Followers: 0</Text>
                                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.secondary, fontSize: SIZES.h4 }}>Follows: 0</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
                            {PLANS.map(plan => {
                                return (
                                    <PlanSummary title={plan.title} author={plan.first_name} picture={plan.picture} key={plan.id} />
                                )
                            })}
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    } else {
        return(
            <Loading />
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile)
```

Comment: Your `Profile` is getting the `auth` from `state.firebase.auth` -- where is that property being updated?  Your `REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS` action doesn't update it.  I suspect that you are mutating an object in state and therefore it won't re-render in response to changes.

Comment: You can combine a lot of the shared logic in the two branches of `if (user.picture)` `else`, but that's unrelated to your issue.

Comment: `state.firebase.auth` comes from the `firebaseReducer` imported from `react-redux-firebase`. And since it works once I refresh I'm guessing firebase updates it?

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes so I checked, I'm getting the currentUser from firebase. I just wonder why when I create the user in my createUser function, it doesn't directly update the displayName and photoURL... because in my function I call the dispatch after the update is complete?